# Configuring TableView with automatic cell height results in no cells displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My goal is to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to show cells with dynamic heights in my TableView. At the moment, *no cells* show up in my tableview after enabling `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Here is my current configuration:

1. I am using a custom cell class, called `FeedCell`
2. `FeedCell` has a view called `ForegroundContainerView`, which has been configured as such where all sides are pinned. [image]
3. I have also tried to pin the `ContentView` of the cell, but was unable to: [image]
4. Lastly, I have the following in `viewDidLoad`:

   `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
   `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 112.0`

(I also deleted the default function `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`

If I don't use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, the cells appear normally, confirming that the data is fed into the tableview correctly.

What am I doing wrong? Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Nice job describing the problem and what you've tried. What you've described sounds like it should work, you may want to consider adding something to the Foreground Container View that has some intrinsic height that the cell can use to determine it's height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your constraints are ambiguous. You are asking UIKit to automatically size your cell (`UITableViewAutomaticDimension`), but the "Foreground Container View" does not have a defined height...it is only constrained to the cell itself (which also doesn't have a defined height!).

So you probably have some kind of ambiguous constraint warning in the console since the system doesn't know what to do, or it's possible your "Foreground Container View" is defaulting to a height of 0.0 meaning your table cell height is about 10.5 (0.0 + your constrained spacing). You didn't include a screenshot of what actually shows in the simulator, so I'm just guessing.

Give your "Foreground Container View" some content or explicitly constrain it's height to something you will be able to see (ex. 200px). Also I recommend you give it a background color so you can actually see it's height on your screen.

---

To get automatic cell sizing with actual cell content, you should constrain views (labels, images, whatever else) inside your "Foreground Container View" (or if you want, inside the cell's content view directly).

There must be both a top spacing and bottom spacing constraint between the anticipated tallest subviews (labels, images, etc.) and the container.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I was unable to constraint the cell `ContainerView` to a height, but will report the results if I constraint `FregroundContainerView` to a specific height.

Comment: You were dead on. When giving the cell a background color, it become apparent that all the cells were just 10.5 in height. When `ForegroundContainerView` was constrained to a height like 200, all the content showed up. The main question is: how do I dynamically constraint `ForegroundContainerView` so that the height is adjustable based on the cell's content?

Comment: @daspianist You constrain the Foreground container view to it's contents (it's subviews). It doesn't look like you have any subviews of the foreground container view right now, though. I updated my answer with a little more info about this.

Comment: This makes sense. I programmatically added views to the cell but did not constraint them, and thus the cell height was unable to be calculated. Thanks for the explanation!